# How to use bootstrap gradient mixin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

How is the gradient mixin used? The mixin file states this:

`#gradient {
.vertical(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%) {`

Ive tried `#gradient.vertical()`, `#gradient > .vertical()` etc. etc..

Do I need to import something?

This is using nemo64:bootstrap less package with meteor

Answer (score 2):

For example to style the background of the entire webpage use:

```
body {
  #gradient > .vertical(@start-color; @end-color);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`#gradient > .vertical();` should work. Make sure you have `@import`ed the mixins.

<strike>For bootstrap you can import both `less/mixins.less` or `less/mixins/gradients.less`.</strike>

As already explained by @Robert you should call the mixin inside a selector:

```
@import "less/mixins";
div {
#gradient > .vertical();
}
```

outputs:

```
div {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555555 0%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #555555 0%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #555555 0%, #333333 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff555555', endColorstr='#ff333333', GradientType=0);
}
```

> This is using nemo64:bootstrap less package with meteor

You should read https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-bootstrap/issues/4 which contains some examples.

@nemo64 wrotes:

> the bootstrap mixins and variables are available though
>   custom.bootstrap.import.less which only contains mixins and variables
>   so you can import it as often as you like.

So you should import `custom.bootstrap.import.less` before calling the mixin.

**update**

> so..shouldnt #gradient > .vertical(#ff0000, #00ff00, 50%, 50%); work?

Yes, it should. Example

After `meteor create test-app` do `cd test-app` then run `meteor add nemo64:bootstrap less`.

Now create a empty `custom.bootstrap.json`, you file structure should look like that shown beneath now:

```
├── custom.bootstrap.json
├── test-app.css
├── test-app.html
└── test-app.js
```

After running the `meteor` command your file structure should become as follows:

```
├── custom.bootstrap.json
├── custom.bootstrap.less
├── custom.bootstrap.mixins.import.less
├── test-app.css
├── test-app.html
└── test-app.js
```

Then create a `gradient.less` file which should contain the following Less code:

```
h1 {
#gradient > .vertical(#ff0000, #00ff00, 50%, 50%);
}
```

Run the `meteor` command again, now your app on `http://localhost:3000/` should look like that shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: `custom.bootstrap.import.less` is where im trying to use the mixins. I have `custom.bootstrap.mixins.import.less` imported at the beginning of the file. The syntax for the gradient specified in the `mixins.import.less` file is `.vertical(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%)` so..shouldnt `#gradient > .vertical(#ff0000, #00ff00, 50%, 50%);` work?